# Exogenous variables in state-space models (entering states versus entering observations)

Tags: state-space-models, exogeneity

From Shumway & Stoffer, Chapter 6 "State-Space Models" page 290: "*...exogenous variables, or fixed inputs, may enter into states or into observations*". Can somebody help me understand the difference between exogenous variables entering states versus observations? Perhaps explaining via a simple example of each will work best.